# Oracle function for dynamic sql pivoting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I found this amazing function in this [article](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/). the function turns a set of values in one of the columns into the column headings :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
type PivotImpl as object
(
  ret_type anytype,      -- The return type of the table function
  stmt varchar2(32767),

  fmt  varchar2(32767),
  cur integer,
  static function ODCITableDescribe( rtype out anytype, p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number := 0 )
  return number,
  static function ODCITablePrepare( sctx out PivotImpl, ti in sys.ODCITabFuncInfo, p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number := 0 )
  return number,
  static function ODCITableStart( sctx in out PivotImpl, p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number := 0 )
  return number,
  member function ODCITableFetch( self in out PivotImpl, nrows in number, outset out anydataset )
  return number,
  member function ODCITableClose( self in PivotImpl )
  return number
)
/

create or replace type body PivotImpl as
  static function ODCITableDescribe( rtype out anytype, p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number )
  return number
  is
    atyp anytype;
    cur integer;
    numcols number;
    desc_tab dbms_sql.desc_tab2;
    rc s

ys_refcursor;
    t_c2 varchar2(32767);
    t_fmt varchar2(1000);
  begin
    cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse( cur, p_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns2( cur, numcols, desc_tab );
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( cur );
--
    anytype.begincreate( dbms_types.typecode_object, atyp );
    for i in 1 .. numcols - 2
    loop
      atyp.addattr( desc_tab( i ).col_name
                  , case desc_tab( i ).col_type
                      when 1   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                      when 2   then dbms_types.typecode_number
                      when 9   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                      when 11  then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2  -- show rowid as varchar2
                      when 12  then dbms_types.typecode_date
                      when 208 then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2  -- show urowid as varchar2
                      when 96  then dbms_types.typecode_char
                      when 180 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
                      when 181 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
                      when 231 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
                      when 182 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
                      when 183 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
                    end
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_precision
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_scale
                  , case desc_tab( i ).col_type
                      when 11 then 18  -- for rowid col_max_len = 16, and 18 characters are shown
                      else desc_tab( i ).col_max_len
                    end
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_charsetid
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_charsetform
                  );
    end loop;
    if instr( p_fmt, '@p@' ) > 0
    then
      t_fmt := p_fmt;
    else
      t_fmt := '@p@';
    end if;
    open rc for replace( 'select distinct ' || t_fmt || '
                          from( ' || p_stmt || ' )
                          order by ' || t_fmt
                       , '@p@'
                       , desc_tab( numcols - 1 ).col_name
                       );
    loop
      fetch rc into t_c2;
      exit when rc%notfound;
      atyp.addattr( t_c2
                  , case desc_tab( numcols ).col_type
                    when 1   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                    when 2   then dbms_types.typecode_number
                    when 9   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                    when 11  then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2  -- show rowid as varchar2
                    when 12  then dbms_types.typecode_date
                    when 208 then dbms_types.typecode_urowid
                    when 96  then dbms_types.typecode_char
                    when 180 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
                    when 181 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
                    when 231 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
                    when 182 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
                    when 183 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
                  end
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_precision
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_scale
                , case desc_tab( numcols ).col_type
                    when 11 then 18  -- for rowid col_max_len = 16, and 18 characters are shown
                    else desc_tab( numcols ).col_max_len
                  end
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_charsetid
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_charsetform
                  );
    end loop;
    close rc;
    atyp.endcreate;
    anytype.begincreate( dbms_types.typecode_table, rtype );
    rtype.SetInfo( null, null, null, null, null, atyp, dbms_types.typecode_object, 0 );
    rtype.endcreate();
    return odciconst.success;
  exception
    when others then
      return odciconst.error;
  end;
--
  static function ODCITablePrepare( sctx out PivotImpl, ti in sys.ODCITabFuncInfo, p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number )
  return number
  is
    prec     pls_integer;
    scale    pls_integer;
    len      pls_integer;
    csid     pls_integer;
    csfrm    pls_integer;
    elem_typ anytype;
    aname    varchar2(30);
    tc       pls_integer;
  begin
    tc := ti.RetType.GetAttrElemInfo( 1, prec, scale, len, csid, csfrm, elem_typ, aname );
--
    if instr( p_fmt, '@p@' ) > 0
    then
      sctx := PivotImpl( elem_typ, p_stmt, p_fmt, null );
    else
      sctx := PivotImpl( elem_typ, p_stmt, '@p@', null );
    end if;
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
--
  static function ODCITableStart( sctx in out PivotImpl, p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number )
  return number
  is
    cur         integer;
    numcols     number;
    desc_tab    dbms_sql.desc_tab2;
    t_stmt      varchar2(32767);
    type_code   pls_integer;
    prec        pls_integer;
    scale       pls_integer;
    len         pls_integer;
    csid        pls_integer;
    csfrm       pls_integer;
    schema_name varchar2(30);
    type_name   varchar2(30);
    version     varchar2(30);
    attr_count  pls_integer;
    attr_type   anytype;
    attr_name   varchar2(100);
    dummy2      integer;
  begin
    cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse( cur, p_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns2( cur, numcols, desc_tab );
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( cur );
--
    for i in 1 .. numcols - 2
    loop
      t_stmt := t_stmt || ', "' || desc_tab( i ).col_name || '"';
    end loop;
--
    type_code := sctx.ret_type.getinfo( prec
                                      , scale
                                      , len
                                      , csid
                                      , csfrm
                                      , schema_name
                                      , type_name
                                      , version
                                      , attr_count
                                      );
    for i in numcols - 1 .. attr_count
    loop
      type_code := sctx.ret_type.getattreleminfo( i
                                                 , prec
                                                 , scale
                                                 , len
                                                 , csid
                                                 , csfrm
                                                 , attr_type
                                                 , attr_name
                                                 );
      t_stmt := t_stmt || replace( ', max( decode( ' || sctx.fmt || ', ''' || attr_name || ''', ' || desc_tab( numcols ).col_name || ' ) )'
                                 , '@p@'
                                 , desc_tab( numcols - 1 ).col_name
                                 );
    end loop;
    t_stmt := 'select ' || substr( t_stmt, 2 ) || ' from ( ' || sctx.stmt || ' )';
    for i in 1 .. numcols - 2
    loop
      if i = 1
      then
        t_stmt := t_stmt || ' group by "' || desc_tab( i ).col_name || '"';
      else
        t_stmt := t_stmt || ', "' || desc_tab( i ).col_name || '"';
      end if;
    end loop;
--
dbms_output.put_line( t_stmt );
    sctx.cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse( sctx.cur, t_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
    for i in 1 .. attr_count
    loop
      type_code := sctx.ret_type.getattreleminfo( i
                                                 , prec
                                                 , scale
                                                 , len
                                                 , csid
                                                 , csfrm
                                                 , attr_type
                                                 , attr_name
                                                 );
      case type_code
        when dbms_types.typecode_char          then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, 'x', 32767 );
        when dbms_types.typecode_varchar2      then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, 'x', 32767 );
        when dbms_types.typecode_number        then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as number ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_date          then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as date ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_urowid        then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as urowid ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp     then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as timestamp ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz  then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as timestamp with time zone ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as timestamp with local time zone ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym   then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as interval year to month ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds   then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as interval day to second ) );
      end case;
    end loop;
    dummy2 := dbms_sql.execute( sctx.cur );
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
--
  member function ODCITableFetch( self in out PivotImpl, nrows in number, outset out anydataset )
  return number
  is
    c1_col_type pls_integer;
    type_code   pls_integer;
    prec        pls_integer;
    scale       pls_integer;
    len         pls_integer;
    csid        pls_integer;
    csfrm       pls_integer;
    schema_name varchar2(30);
    type_name   varchar2(30);
    version     varchar2(30);
    attr_count  pls_integer;
    attr_type   anytype;
    attr_name   varchar2(100);
    v1     varchar2(32767);
    n1     number;
    d1     date;
    ur1    urowid;
    ids1   interval day to second;
    iym1   interval year to month;
    ts1    timestamp;
    tstz1  timestamp with time zone;
    tsltz1 timestamp with local time zone;
  begin
    outset := null;
    if nrows < 1
    then
-- is this possible???
      return odciconst.success;
    end if;
--
dbms_output.put_line( 'fetch' );
    if dbms_sql.fetch_rows( self.cur ) = 0
    then
      return odciconst.success;
    end if;
--
dbms_output.put_line( 'done' );
    type_code := self.ret_type.getinfo( prec
                                      , scale
                                      , len
                                      , csid
                                      , csfrm
                                      , schema_name
                                      , type_name
                                      , version
                                      , attr_count
                                      );
    anydataset.begincreate( dbms_types.typecode_object, self.ret_type, outset );
    outset.addinstance;
    outset.piecewise();
    for i in 1 .. attr_count
    loop
      type_code := self.ret_type.getattreleminfo( i
                                                 , prec
                                                 , scale
                                                 , len
                                                 , csid
                                                 , csfrm
                                                 , attr_type
                                                 , attr_name
                                                 );
dbms_output.put_line( attr_name );
        case type_code
          when dbms_types.typecode_char then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, v1 );
            outset.setchar( v1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_varchar2 then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, v1 );
            outset.setvarchar2( v1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_number then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, n1 );
            outset.setnumber( n1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_date then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, d1 );
            outset.setdate( d1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_urowid then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, ur1 );
            outset.seturowid( ur1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, ids1 );

    outset.setintervalds( ids1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, iym1 );
            outset.setintervalym( iym1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, ts1 );
            outset.settimestamp( ts1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, tstz1 );
            outset.settimestamptz( tstz1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, tsltz1 );
            outset.settimestampltz( tsltz1 );
        end case;
    end loop;
    outset.endcreate;
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
--
  member function ODCITableClose( self in PivotImpl )
  return number
  is
    c integer;
  begin
    c := self.cur;
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( c );
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
end;
/

create or replace
function pivot( p_stmt in varchar2, p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)', dummy in number := 0 )
return anydataset pipelined using PivotImpl;
/
```

Unfortunately, the function does not order the columns : the result of my select query is :

```
ID              NAME            EDITS           DAYS
1               Example         Edt1            10
1               Example         Edt2            5
1               Example         Edt3            3
```

When I use the `pivot` function I lose the order :

```
Select * from table (PIVOT('My select query')); 

ID              NAME            Edt2            Edt1        Edt3
1               Example         5               10          3
```

Can you please help me edit this function to keep the order of the columns as it was with the values of the initial column ? thanks.

**UPDATE :** My select query :

```
SELECT  ID_DEMAND
        , NAME 
        , EDIT 
        , LEAD (EDIT_START) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_DEMAND ORDER BY ORDER_EDIT) - EDIT_START AS TOTAL
            FROM (
                    SELECT 
                    ID_DEMAND
                    , NAME
                    , EDIT
                    , ORDER_EDIT
                    , MIN (DATE_ACTION) as EDIT_START
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT 
                              D.ID_DEMAND
                              , J.NAME
                              , L.DATE_ACTION
                              , L.EDIT
                              , L.ORDER_EDIT
                                  FROM (DEMAND D LEFT JOIN LOG L ON D.ID_DEMAND = L.ID_DEMAND) 
                                  LEFT JOIN JOB J ON D.ID_JOB = J.ID_JOB )T
            GROUP BY 
                  ID_DEMAND
                  , NAME
                  , EDIT
                  , ORDER_EDIT)
            JHERE ID_DEMAND = 1601
            ORDER BY ID_DEMAND, ORDER_EDIT
```

Comment: How are you defining the order of the columns; from the varchar2 sort order of the EDITS value? With a quick test I get the columns in that order. Can you add table and data setup to recreate the issue?

Comment: the order is defined using a column where each edit has its predefined order (i'm not using the value of the edits). just updated my question with the select query.

Comment: I meant why you think the order you get is wrong. What are the actual values for `EDIT` - what you showed in the question, more varied, different cases? I don't think you'd get those exact pivot headers unless you passed the `p_fmt` argument, which makes me think you've edited the values - possibly hiding the problem...

Comment: yes the edits are different, each demand has a set of predefined edits ( more complex names ..that's why I used dummy names on my example ^^ )

Comment: But we can't see those values, so we don't know what order the pivot currently puts them in, and what order you expect them to be in. The code is ordering by `EDITS` value; well, `upper(EDITS)` by default. You can possibly come up with a `p_fmt` that generates the order you want, or change your query, but we don't have enough info to tell you how (or if it is possible).

Answer (score 2):

The function you're using ignores the ordering of the value you set with your `order by` clause, and bases the pivoted column names and their sequence on the sorted values from that in the result set - based on the default second parameter to `pivot` being left as `upper(@p)`, which gets translated to `upper(EDIT)` later on. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to get the result you want, because that ordering has to be based on the penultimate `EDIT` field - it can be left as lower case or manipulated some other way, but not a way that does what you want.

You can modify the implementation to require and consume an addition ordering column, effectively turning the `pivot` function definition into:

```
create or replace
function pivot( p_stmt in varchar2,
  p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
  p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
  dummy in number := 0 )
return anydataset pipelined using PivotImpl;
/
```

This has an additional ordering placeholder, which I've defaulted to `'@o@'` in the spirit of the existing one, and which could potentially also allow some manipulation. That has to be reflected in all the `PivotImpl` function declarations, and then has to be used in the cursor that extracts the column values and decides their ordering. I've done that as:

```
open rc for replace( replace( 'select ' || t_fmt || '
                      from( ' || p_stmt || ' )
                      group by ' || t_fmt || '
                      order by min(' || t_ord || ')'
                   , '@p@'
                   , desc_tab( numcols - 1 ).col_name
                   )
                   , '@o@'
                   , desc_tab( numcols - 2 ).col_name
                   );
```

This means that your `ORDER_EDIT` value has to be included in the select list, and has to be in the column position before `EDIT` with the way I've modified the column number handling; but also means your existing `order by` clause is redundant.

With some really simple dummy data set up:

```
create table job (id_job number, name varchar2(10));
create table demand (id_demand number, id_job number);
create table log (id_demand number, edit varchar2(4),
  order_edit number, date_action date);

insert into job values (42, 'Name');
insert into demand values (1601, 42);
insert into log values (1601, 'EdtC', 1, sysdate);
insert into log values (1601, 'EdtA', 2, sysdate);
insert into log values (1601, 'EdtB', 3, sysdate);
```

Your inner query gets:

```
 ID_DEMAND NAME       EDIT      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ---- ----------
      1601 Name       EdtC          0
      1601 Name       EdtA          0
      1601 Name       EdtB
```

The original implementation gets:

```
 ID_DEMAND NAME             EDTA       EDTB       EDTC
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1601 Name                0                     0
```

And this modified implementation called with:

```
Select * from table (PIVOT('SELECT  ID_DEMAND
        , NAME 
        , ORDER_EDIT
        , EDIT 
        , LEAD (EDIT_START) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_DEMAND ORDER BY ORDER_EDIT) - EDIT_START AS TOTAL
            FROM (
                    SELECT 
                    ID_DEMAND
                    , NAME
                    , EDIT
                    , ORDER_EDIT
                    , MIN (DATE_ACTION) as EDIT_START
                          FROM 
                              (SELECT 
                              D.ID_DEMAND
                              , J.NAME
                              , L.DATE_ACTION
                              , L.EDIT
                              , L.ORDER_EDIT
                                  FROM (DEMAND D LEFT JOIN LOG L ON D.ID_DEMAND = L.ID_DEMAND) 
                                  LEFT JOIN JOB J ON D.ID_JOB = J.ID_JOB )T
            GROUP BY 
                  ID_DEMAND
                  , NAME
                  , EDIT
                  , ORDER_EDIT)
            WHERE ID_DEMAND = 1601'));
```

... with `ORDER_EDIT` included in the select list, so the result set now looks like:

```
 ID_DEMAND NAME       ORDER_EDIT EDIT      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----------
      1601 Name                1 EdtC          0
      1601 Name                2 EdtA          0
      1601 Name                3 EdtB
```

The modified function call gets:

```
 ID_DEMAND NAME             EDTC       EDTA       EDTB
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1601 Name                0          0
```

Which has the pivoted columns in the order specified by your flag, which is what I think you want to achieve.

---

This is the whole modified implementation, which is too large for SQL Fiddle. I've marked the bits I've changed with `-- added` and `-- changed` comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
type PivotImpl as object
(
  ret_type anytype,      -- The return type of the table function
  stmt varchar2(32767),

  fmt  varchar2(32767),
  ord  varchar2(32767), -- added
  cur integer,
  static function ODCITableDescribe( rtype out anytype,
    p_stmt in varchar2,
    p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
    p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
    dummy in number := 0 )
  return number,
  static function ODCITablePrepare( sctx out PivotImpl,
    ti in sys.ODCITabFuncInfo,
    p_stmt in varchar2,
    p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
    p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
    dummy in number := 0 )
  return number,
  static function ODCITableStart( sctx in out PivotImpl,
    p_stmt in varchar2,
    p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
    p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
    dummy in number := 0 )
  return number,
  member function ODCITableFetch( self in out PivotImpl,
    nrows in number,
    outset out anydataset )
  return number,
  member function ODCITableClose( self in PivotImpl )
  return number
)
/

create or replace type body PivotImpl as
  static function ODCITableDescribe( rtype out anytype,
    p_stmt in varchar2,
    p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
    p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
    dummy in number )
  return number
  is
    atyp anytype;
    cur integer;
    numcols number;
    desc_tab dbms_sql.desc_tab2;
    rc sys_refcursor;
    t_c2 varchar2(32767);
    t_fmt varchar2(1000);
    t_ord varchar2(1000); -- added
  begin
    cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse( cur, p_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns2( cur, numcols, desc_tab );
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( cur );
--
    anytype.begincreate( dbms_types.typecode_object, atyp );
    for i in 1 .. numcols - 3 -- changed
    loop
      atyp.addattr( desc_tab( i ).col_name
                  , case desc_tab( i ).col_type
                      when 1   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                      when 2   then dbms_types.typecode_number
                      when 9   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                      when 11  then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2  -- show rowid as varchar2
                      when 12  then dbms_types.typecode_date
                      when 208 then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2  -- show urowid as varchar2
                      when 96  then dbms_types.typecode_char
                      when 180 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
                      when 181 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
                      when 231 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
                      when 182 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
                      when 183 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
                    end
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_precision
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_scale
                  , case desc_tab( i ).col_type
                      when 11 then 18  -- for rowid col_max_len = 16, and 18 characters are shown
                      else desc_tab( i ).col_max_len
                    end
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_charsetid
                  , desc_tab( i ).col_charsetform
                  );
    end loop;
    if instr( p_fmt, '@p@' ) > 0
    then
      t_fmt := p_fmt;
    else
      t_fmt := '@p@';
    end if;
    -- added, but not really implemented
    if instr( p_ord, '@o@' ) > 0
    then
      t_ord := p_ord;
    else
      t_ord := '@o@';
    end if;
    -- changed cursor/replace to handle ordering
    open rc for replace( replace( 'select ' || t_fmt || '
                          from( ' || p_stmt || ' )
                          group by ' || t_fmt || '
                          order by min(' || t_ord || ')'
                       , '@p@'
                       , desc_tab( numcols - 1 ).col_name
                       )
                       , '@o@'
                       , desc_tab( numcols - 2 ).col_name
                       );
    loop
      fetch rc into t_c2;
      exit when rc%notfound;
      atyp.addattr( t_c2
                  , case desc_tab( numcols ).col_type
                    when 1   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                    when 2   then dbms_types.typecode_number
                    when 9   then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
                    when 11  then dbms_types.typecode_varchar2  -- show rowid as varchar2
                    when 12  then dbms_types.typecode_date
                    when 208 then dbms_types.typecode_urowid
                    when 96  then dbms_types.typecode_char
                    when 180 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp
                    when 181 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz
                    when 231 then dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz
                    when 182 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym
                    when 183 then dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds
                  end
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_precision
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_scale
                , case desc_tab( numcols ).col_type
                    when 11 then 18  -- for rowid col_max_len = 16, and 18 characters are shown
                    else desc_tab( numcols ).col_max_len
                  end
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_charsetid
                , desc_tab( numcols ).col_charsetform
                  );
    end loop;
    close rc;
    atyp.endcreate;
    anytype.begincreate( dbms_types.typecode_table, rtype );
    rtype.SetInfo( null, null, null, null, null, atyp, dbms_types.typecode_object, 0 );
    rtype.endcreate();
    return odciconst.success;
  exception
    when others then
      return odciconst.error;
  end;
--
  static function ODCITablePrepare( sctx out PivotImpl,
    ti in sys.ODCITabFuncInfo,
    p_stmt in varchar2,
    p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
    p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
    dummy in number )
  return number
  is
    prec     pls_integer;
    scale    pls_integer;
    len      pls_integer;
    csid     pls_integer;
    csfrm    pls_integer;
    elem_typ anytype;
    aname    varchar2(30);
    tc       pls_integer;
  begin
    tc := ti.RetType.GetAttrElemInfo( 1, prec, scale, len, csid, csfrm, elem_typ, aname );
--
    if instr( p_fmt, '@p@' ) > 0
    then
      sctx := PivotImpl( elem_typ, p_stmt, p_fmt, p_ord, null ); -- changed
    else
      sctx := PivotImpl( elem_typ, p_stmt, '@p@', '@o@', null ); -- changed
    end if;
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
--
  static function ODCITableStart( sctx in out PivotImpl,
    p_stmt in varchar2,
    p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
    p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
    dummy in number )
  return number
  is
    cur         integer;
    numcols     number;
    desc_tab    dbms_sql.desc_tab2;
    t_stmt      varchar2(32767);
    type_code   pls_integer;
    prec        pls_integer;
    scale       pls_integer;
    len         pls_integer;
    csid        pls_integer;
    csfrm       pls_integer;
    schema_name varchar2(30);
    type_name   varchar2(30);
    version     varchar2(30);
    attr_count  pls_integer;
    attr_type   anytype;
    attr_name   varchar2(100);
    dummy2      integer;
  begin
    cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse( cur, p_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns2( cur, numcols, desc_tab );
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( cur );
--
    for i in 1 .. numcols - 3 -- changed
    loop
      t_stmt := t_stmt || ', "' || desc_tab( i ).col_name || '"';
    end loop;
--
dbms_output.put_line(t_stmt);
    type_code := sctx.ret_type.getinfo( prec
                                      , scale
                                      , len
                                      , csid
                                      , csfrm
                                      , schema_name
                                      , type_name
                                      , version
                                      , attr_count
                                      );
    for i in numcols - 2 .. attr_count -- changed
    loop
      type_code := sctx.ret_type.getattreleminfo( i
                                                 , prec
                                                 , scale
                                                 , len
                                                 , csid
                                                 , csfrm
                                                 , attr_type
                                                 , attr_name
                                                 );
      t_stmt := t_stmt || replace( ', max( decode( ' || sctx.fmt || ', ''' || attr_name || ''', ' || desc_tab( numcols ).col_name || ' ) )'
                                 , '@p@'
                                 , desc_tab( numcols - 1 ).col_name
                                 );
    end loop;
    t_stmt := 'select ' || substr( t_stmt, 2 ) || ' from ( ' || sctx.stmt || ' )';
    for i in 1 .. numcols - 3 -- changed
    loop
      if i = 1
      then
        t_stmt := t_stmt || ' group by "' || desc_tab( i ).col_name || '"';
      else
        t_stmt := t_stmt || ', "' || desc_tab( i ).col_name || '"';
      end if;
    end loop;
--
    sctx.cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse( sctx.cur, t_stmt, dbms_sql.native );
    for i in 1 .. attr_count
    loop
      type_code := sctx.ret_type.getattreleminfo( i
                                                 , prec
                                                 , scale
                                                 , len
                                                 , csid
                                                 , csfrm
                                                 , attr_type
                                                 , attr_name
                                                 );
      case type_code
        when dbms_types.typecode_char          then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, 'x', 32767 );
        when dbms_types.typecode_varchar2      then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, 'x', 32767 );
        when dbms_types.typecode_number        then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as number ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_date          then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as date ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_urowid        then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as urowid ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp     then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as timestamp ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz  then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as timestamp with time zone ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as timestamp with local time zone ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym   then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as interval year to month ) );
        when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds   then dbms_sql.define_column( sctx.cur, i, cast( null as interval day to second ) );
      end case;
    end loop;
    dummy2 := dbms_sql.execute( sctx.cur );
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
--
  member function ODCITableFetch( self in out PivotImpl,
    nrows in number,
    outset out anydataset )
  return number
  is
    c1_col_type pls_integer;
    type_code   pls_integer;
    prec        pls_integer;
    scale       pls_integer;
    len         pls_integer;
    csid        pls_integer;
    csfrm       pls_integer;
    schema_name varchar2(30);
    type_name   varchar2(30);
    version     varchar2(30);
    attr_count  pls_integer;
    attr_type   anytype;
    attr_name   varchar2(100);
    v1     varchar2(32767);
    n1     number;
    d1     date;
    ur1    urowid;
    ids1   interval day to second;
    iym1   interval year to month;
    ts1    timestamp;
    tstz1  timestamp with time zone;
    tsltz1 timestamp with local time zone;
  begin
    outset := null;
    if nrows < 1
    then
-- is this possible???
      return odciconst.success;
    end if;
--
dbms_output.put_line( 'fetch' );
    if dbms_sql.fetch_rows( self.cur ) = 0
    then
      return odciconst.success;
    end if;
--
dbms_output.put_line( 'done' );
    type_code := self.ret_type.getinfo( prec
                                      , scale
                                      , len
                                      , csid
                                      , csfrm
                                      , schema_name
                                      , type_name
                                      , version
                                      , attr_count
                                      );
    anydataset.begincreate( dbms_types.typecode_object, self.ret_type, outset );
    outset.addinstance;
    outset.piecewise();
    for i in 1 .. attr_count
    loop
      type_code := self.ret_type.getattreleminfo( i
                                                 , prec
                                                 , scale
                                                 , len
                                                 , csid
                                                 , csfrm
                                                 , attr_type
                                                 , attr_name
                                                 );
dbms_output.put_line( attr_name );
        case type_code
          when dbms_types.typecode_char then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, v1 );
            outset.setchar( v1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_varchar2 then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, v1 );
            outset.setvarchar2( v1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_number then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, n1 );
            outset.setnumber( n1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_date then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, d1 );
            outset.setdate( d1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_urowid then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, ur1 );
            outset.seturowid( ur1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ds then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, ids1 );

    outset.setintervalds( ids1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_interval_ym then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, iym1 );
            outset.setintervalym( iym1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, ts1 );
            outset.settimestamp( ts1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_tz then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, tstz1 );
            outset.settimestamptz( tstz1 );
          when dbms_types.typecode_timestamp_ltz then
            dbms_sql.column_value( self.cur, i, tsltz1 );
            outset.settimestampltz( tsltz1 );
        end case;
    end loop;
    outset.endcreate;
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
--
  member function ODCITableClose( self in PivotImpl )
  return number
  is
    c integer;
  begin
    c := self.cur;
    dbms_sql.close_cursor( c );
    return odciconst.success;
  end;
end;
/

create or replace
function pivot( p_stmt in varchar2,
  p_fmt in varchar2 := 'upper(@p@)',
  p_ord in varchar2 := '@o@', -- added
  dummy in number := 0 )
return anydataset pipelined using PivotImpl;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this same pivot and ran into the same issue.  The dynamic pivot that you mention orders the pivoted columns alphabetically.  The hacky workaround I found is to use a case statements to add characters
something like

```
SELECT 
                    ID_DEMAND
                    , NAME
                    , CASE
                    WHEN EDIT < 'EDIT2' THEN ' EDIT2'
                    WHEN EDIT > 'EDIT4' THEN '_EDIT4'
                    ELSE EDIT
                    END AS EDIT,
                    , ORDER_EDIT
                    , MIN (DATE_ACTION) as EDIT_START
```

This lacks sophistication and style but gets the job done.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have predefined values for my edits (the names may vary and can be changed from a dedicated table) so i wont be able to compare :/

Comment: @RidRoid - so how do you know what order you want them in? Is that defined in the dedicated table, with a sequence/priority column for example, that you can join to and use in the case?

Comment: @AlexPoole there is `ORDER BY ID_DEMAND, ORDER_EDIT`in my initial `select`query.. but once I pass the query as a parameter that order is lost.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to code modification if you do not care about the column name...

ROWNUM will give the number I believe to be the same ordering as original ordering.

ROWNUM does not sort correctly on its own due to textual sorting.

IE: 
1,10,11,12,2,20,21,22

If you do not care about the column names, then

prefixing or padding the numbers with 0 allows for "normal" sorting behaviour.

IE
001,002,003,004,005,006,007

or

001 col name 1,002 col name 2, 003 col name 3

if concatenation is used to maintain to a degree the original column name

NOTE:
to_number does not appear to work as I believe internally this gets massaged back to text.